# I Want to store firebase child's data to Arraylist

Tags: android

I have an Android application connected to firebase, I add the data in  firebase manually but I want to fetch it and store it in an `ArrayList` with type `Object`,  here is my firebase :

[image]

My Array :

```
ArrayList<Character> CharacterList = new ArrayList<>();
```

My Character Class :

```
public class Character {

    private String name , Description , imageurl ;

    public Character() {

    }

    public Character(String name, String desc , String imgurl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.Description = desc;
        this.imageurl = imgurl;
    }

    public String getname(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return this.Description;
    }

    public String getImageurl(){
        return this.imageurl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `DatabaseReference` like this:

```
DatabaseReference database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yourChild");
```

and then use `addChildEventListener`:

```
  database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Character character = dataSnapshot.getValue(Character.class);
            CharacterList.add(character);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
```

Comment: Sorry to ask i'm still new to this , if you saw my firebase data at the image , can you tell me what should i put in " YourChild "   ? is it Char1 or Characters ? if Char1 what if i have more  Char's ?

Comment: You should type Characters 
`DatabaseReference database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Characters");`

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side under the vote arrows. Should change the color in green. Thanks!